# Return Selected Fields in Json for API calls in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Is there a way to return only **specific** fields, in Json, when the **specific** API is called.  I have used "transient":  but that would be at the Object level and thus make it true for all API calls.

Example:  The complete Json is

```
[{"field1":"a","field2":"b","field3":"c"},{"field1":"d","field2":"e","field3":"f"},{"field1":"g","field2":"h","field3":"i"}]
```

Depending on the API calls for a **specific** user, the "json output" is specific for the API call. It could be any one of the following depending on the API call.

```
[{"field1":"a"},{"field1":"d"},{"field1":"g"}]
```

OR

```
[{"field2":"b"},{"field2":"e"},{"field2":"h"}]
```

OR

```
[{"field3":"c"},{"field3":"f"},{"field3":"i"}]
```

OR  a combination of the above.

E.g.  The code for the above example is shown below.

```
public class childObj {

    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public String field3;


    public childObj(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        super();
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

}
```

The Main Class is defined Below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class ParentAndChildObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<childObj> childObjList    = new ArrayList<childObj>();

        childObjList.add(new childObj("a","b","c"));
        childObjList.add(new childObj("d","e","f"));
        childObjList.add(new childObj("g","h","i"));

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        String myString = gson.toJson(childObjList);

        System.out.println(myString);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson, a standard JSON lib in Java, you may use the @View annotation to filter what you want in the resulting object.

For dynamic selections, you'll have to use specific annotations as per your requirement. This link should help you -> http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html

For instance, for fully dynamic filtering, look at the use of @JsonFilter